# Extracting values to points - not all points extracted

Tags: raster, arcmap, extract

I have a raster from which I would like to extract Z info at specific points. I have the points saved as a shapefile as below. There are 144000 points (72 transects with 2000m length each). When I use 'extract values to points', not all points are extracted, I get around 139385 points instead. I would like to have exactly 144,000 points - one rastervalue per point. I have checked that Geostatistical Analysis - Coincidental Points is set to 'INCLUDE_ALL', but apart from that, I'm not sure where I could be going wrong.

[image]

Comment: Some of them outside raster. Try extract multivalues to point to see them

Comment: Thanks @FelixIP. Some points being outside raster shouldn't make a difference, those values would just be extracted as 0 or NaN. I ended up getting the equivalent approach to work fine in QGIS using 'Sample raster values'.